# Sails.js Sending json object returned in https.request to the view

Tags: javascript, json, api, sails.js

Just learning Sails.js so go easy on me.

I have queried an XML service and successfully jsonified it using `xml2js`

```
var req = https.request(options, function(res) {

    var xml = '';
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        xml += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', function () {

        var result = parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result)); // Position 1
        });

        return result;
    });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message); 
});

req.write(data);

var result = req.end();

        console.log('Result: ' + JSON.stringify(result)); // Position 2

res.view({ message : 'hello', result : result });
```

The view is loading fine, and `<%= message %>` outputs `hello`. Great.

Position1 console.log is returning the stringified json object - Great.

Position 2 consile.log is returning `Result: true` - Not good.

I need to be able to get that json data to my view for parsing. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're assuming that calling `req.end()` will give you the response from the `https.request` you started above.  There are a couple of things wrong with that:

1. `req.end()` is used to finish writing to an open request, not to get a response.  According to [the docs](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_end_data_encoding), the return value is unspecified.
2. The `https.request` call is asynchronous; even if `req.end()` worked like you want it to, the response wouldn't have come in by the time you call it.

The solution is to put your response code (i.e. your `res.view`) inside the handler for the `end` event that you've already written.  I'd also recommend refactoring your code to use different variable names for the remote request / response so that they don't collide with the `req` and `res` variables in your controller action.  The whole thing would then be something like:

```
myAction: function (req, res) {

    // Not sure how you're setting options, so just an example
    var options = {url: 'http://example.com', ...}

    var request = https.request(options, function(response) {

        var xml = '';
        response.on('data', function(chunk) {
            xml += chunk;
        });

        response.on('end', function () {

            var result = parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
                return res.view({ message : 'hello', result : JSON.stringify(result)});
            });

        });
    });

    request.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message); 
        res.serverError(e); 
    });
}
```

You might also look into using something like the [Request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module to simplify your external request; it would save you from having to write event handlers for `data` and `end`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass `json` to some javascript variable:

```
var clientJsonVar = <%- JSON.stringify(serverSideJson)%>
```